# Oracle sql to find single row from duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help on what will be the sql if I want to find contacts which has only single ruleid which is 2. Hence the output should be contact id's 1 and 7.
I am not looking for contact Id 5 & 6 in the output as they have more than one ruleid even though they have got ruleid 2

```
Contactid   ruleid
1                   2
5                   3
5                   2
6                   4
6                   2
7                   2
```

Can someone please help on this.

Comment: Is it possible to have duplicate rows (meaning the same `contactid` **and** the same `ruleid` at the same time)? If for example you have two rows with `contactid = 8` and `ruleid =2` (and no other rows for that `contactid`) what should be the result? ALSO: can either `contactid` or `ruleid` be `NULL`?

Comment: Thx for your reply.  We cannot have duplicate rows where contact Id 8 and ruleid 2 will be repeated.  Also nulls are not allowed in both the columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT Contactid FROM <YOURTABLE> 
WHERE ruleid = 2 
AND Contactid NOT IN 
    (SELECT Contactid FROM <YOURTABLE> 
     WHERE ruleid <> 2)
```

Comment: `not in` may not work as intended if `contactid` may be `NULL`. Also, the correct answer (which would be some variation of aggregate or `GROUP BY` query) should read the base table just once, not twice.

Comment: @mathguy that's right, grouping would be more efficient than using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and will be efficient.

```
select   contactid
from     table_name
group by contactid
having   min(ruleid) = 2 
     and max(ruleid) = 2
```

Comment: Interesting - I see a downvote. Would the downvoter care to share with the community what they found wrong with this query? For the benefit of everyone? Thank you!

Comment: Hi,  your query did wonders for me.. It worked with perfection.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH your_table_name as(
        SELECT 1 AS Contactid   , 2 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 AS Contactid   , 3 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5 AS Contactid   , 2 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6 AS Contactid   , 4 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6 AS Contactid   , 2 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7 AS Contactid   , 2 AS ruleid FROM DUAL
)

SELECT t.* FROM (
      SELECT   Contactid   FROM  your_table_name
      WHERE ruleid = 2
      GROUP BY   Contactid 
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) t
    left JOIN (
      SELECT   Contactid   FROM  your_table_name
      WHERE ruleid <> 2
      GROUP BY   Contactid 
    ) tt
    ON
    t.Contactid = tt.Contactid
    where tt.Contactid is null
```

Comment: Hi I tried this and also added a where condition for ruleid =2 but this did not work.

Comment: My query was select contactid from table where ruleid=2 group by ruleid having count(ruleid) =1

Comment: @sam2539431 - you don't needed adding something. I've updated my answer with CTE   , please see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not enough for you?

```
select contactid from table group by contactid having count(ruleid)=1
```

Comment: This assumes that every `contactid` **will** have a row with `ruleid=2`. This is true in the sample data provided, but it is not stated as a guarantee in the problem statement. (It may still be true though!)

Comment: Hi,  thx for your reply.  It is possible that a contact may not have ruleid 2

Comment: Thx Renato for your reply.  I specifically needed for ruleid=2 however I can add one more select out of your query to find ruleid=2.. I will try this today.  Thx